# converting the serial read(ASCII) to floating number

Tags: python

I am retrieving serial output from the Arduino through my Raspberry Pi(python).

The code used :

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',115200)
while True:
    value = float(ser.readline().strip())
    print '{0:0.2f}'.format(value)
```

Problem: I am able to print the serial output removing the unwanted characters for few of the readings, after that it gives an error " valueError :could not convert string to float:"

Comment: Float string, hex, byte, which is incoming ? All are got different extraction method. You need check `byte size` if float is `hex` style(32,64,128,256 bit). `'{0:0.2f}'.format(float(value))`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I tried to read the data too fast. Found that out by also printing the ASCII data (before conversion to float). Sometimes it printed as an empty line. I just slowed the loop down:

```
while True:
   # readline, etc
   time.sleep(1)
```

First I had:

time.sleep(.5)

The Arduino also sends the data every .5 seconds, so sometimes there was just no data yet.